# PHP get page name of calling page?

Tags: php, include, filenames

Is there any way of retrieving the page name of the calling page for a php file?

For example, if I have `index.php`:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include 'val.php';
  // other stuff
?>
```

And my `val.php` looks like:

```
<?php
  // get file name of caller (index.php in this case)
?>
```

I can use `echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);` to get the page name if I put the `val.php` code in `index.php`, but I would like this code to appear on multiple pages, so extracting it to its own page is necessary.

Maybe I should put `basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);` into a session variable in `$_SESSION` before calling `include 'val.php'`, then destroy the variable after use? Is that a good idea?

Comment: That would be the [XY problem.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, you can use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];`

That will return the filename which included the val.php in this case.

Answer (score 0):

**pathinfo()** returns information about path: either an associative array or a string, depending on options.

(PHP 4 >= 4.0.3, PHP 5, PHP 7)
pathinfo — Returns information about a file path

**From here** - http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

```
<?php
$path_parts = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/inc/lib.inc.php');

echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n"; // since PHP 5.2.0
?>
```